# Connecting With AWS CLI to instance not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, bitnami

I've created an EC2 instance and used Bitnami image.

When I try to connect to the instance using AWS CLI and either of these users: "bitnami", "ec2-user", "admin", then I get the following error:

```
Failed to connect to your instance
Error establishing SSH connection to your instance. Try again later.
```

When I created the instance for the first time I downloaded a key pair. I can connect with the instance using putty, the downloaded key pair and "bitnami". I wasn't able to connect as "admin" or "ec2-user".

Afterwards I've generated several key pairs and I am unsure which one is the instance using. I noticed that the one it's using is 2 months older than the one I use when connecting with putty.

What precisely I need to do to connect from CLI as "admin" or "ec2-user" to the instance?

Comment: I am confused. "Afterwards I've generated several key pairs and I am unsure which one is the instance using. I noticed that the one it's using is 2 months older than the one I use when connecting with putty." Are you or are you not able to login to the ec2 instance? As for cli, you mean from terminal and not putty? You need to have the .pem file to be able to login via terminal if this is the question.

Comment: @Riz: please consider I am not a cloud expert. I am trying to log in using "Ec2 Instance Connect" and I am getting the error mentioned above. If I go to EC2 Instance and select the instance I see "key value pair" which was generated 2 months after I generated the first key. Not sure if this has any impact, but I thought it was worth mentioning. In either case, I can't connect using "Ec2 Instance Connect" and either of these users "ec2-user", "admin", "bitnami"

Comment: ok so, instance connect has few pre requisits. 1: your instance "should" be in public subnet(should have internet access). 2: only ubuntu 20.04+ and amazon linux 2 2.0.20190618+ have it already installed. if yours is not one of these oses, you need to first install it. 3: You need IAM permissions. I am guessing your haven't configured permissions atleast. I would suggest session manager. No need to open ports, you just need to give some permissions to your instance role and open a port in outbound and that's it.https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/session-manager.html

Comment: @Riz. Here is what I see in Details of the instance: "bitnami-wordpress-6.0.1-2-r02-linux-debian-11-x86_64-hvm-ebs-nami". Is this version eligible for connecting?
How can I check if the instance is in public subnet?
How do I configure IAM permissions? This is what I see when I try to connect with Session Manager: https://prnt.sc/_ZclbTccEYiD

Comment: With putty, when you access the EC2, do you use the ip of the EC2 directly or do you use a bastion host? If you use your EC2 ip directly then you have your instance in public subnet. Unders details(EC2 console), you can see `IAM Role`. Click on it and attach `AmazonSSMFullAccess` permission and try logging in with ssm. Also open outbound on 443 to all(actuallt to few endpoints but for now you can leave it for all communication). If it doesn't work, you need to install/update ssm agent of your instance.

Comment: @Riz: thanks for your quick reply. With Putty I am using this value as "host name / IP address)" --> "bitnami@ec2-<elastic_IP_address>.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com". Under details (EC2 console) I see empty "IAM Role" field: https://prnt.sc/O2_Lg9pTPH3x This field is, however, not editable. How inbound and outbound routes are set, please see screenshots in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75624841/site-unavailable-on-ec2-instance-bitnami-image

Comment: outbound seems ok. You can create a role and attach it following https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html#attach-iam-role

Answer (score 0):

> What precisely I need to do to connect from CLI as "admin" or "ec2-user" to the instance?

You would need at least the following:

- The public key of the private key you are attempting to use should be in `/home/admin/.ssh/authorized_keys` or `/home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys` (assuming those are Linux user accounts on the machine)
- Your SSH client must be configured to use the correct private key (usually with `ssh -i /path/to/private.key`, `~/.ssh/config` or an SSH agent)
- Your SSH client must be set to use the correct username (either with `username@host` or `~/.ssh/config`) otherwise it will try to authenticate as the user you are on the client machine, which is probably something like `dantes` that doesn't exist on the ec2
- The firewall of the EC2 must allow inbound connections on port 22 from your IP
- The EC2 must have a public IP

I think AWS has a browser based SSH client as well which might be easier. This is explained in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html

Comment: @Dommndke Thanks for your message. I am not sure if you understood me correctly (or I misunderstood something) but I can connect with "bitnami" user using Putty. The issue I have when I connect as "bitnami" user is that I can't run certain commands such as "sudo systemctl status httpd". I need this to resolve an issue with the instance/bitnami. In some videos I've seen that when the connection is made with "ec2-user" the commands can be run. For that reason I am trying to connect as "e2-user". (Does not work over putty, so I try with "Instance Connect")
I have seen that when I connect as "

Comment: @Dantes That's probably because the `bitnami` user is not in the `/etc/sudoers` file on that machine. Either you must add it to that file, or you must add your key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` of another user that can sudo. Of course both of those things normally requires sudo, so it's a kind of catch-22. Cloud machines should already be set up to allow SSH as a sudo-capable user, you just have to figure out which user and which key. I'd carefully read their docs, or contact their support.