# Site Unavailable on EC2 Instance (Bitnami Image)

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, bitnami

i've installed Bitnami image (for Wordpress) on top of EC2 instance.

After stopping and again starting an instance I am getting this error when I try to access the site over browser:

```
ec2-<IP_address>.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com refused to connect.
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

My setup looks like this:

- 1 EC2 instance
- There is 1 VPC
- There is 1 route table (public hosting zone)
- There is 1 network ACL
- There is 1 elastic IP which seems to be connected to VPC and EC2
- There are 4 security groups all connected to that 1 VPC (3/4 groups are bitnami, 1 is default)
- 1 internet gateway
- 1 DHCP option set

EC2 instance has 1 elastic IP and they are associated. The same IP is seen in routing table as A record.
Instance details:

- Platform: Debian, Linux/UNIX
- AMI name: bitnami-wordpress-6.0.1-2-r02-linux-debian-11-x86_64-hvm-ebs-nami-7d426cb7-9522-4dd7-a56b-55dd8cc1c8d0
- AMI location: aws-marketplace/bitnami-wordpress-6.0.1-2-r02-linux-debian-11-x86_64-hvm-ebs-nami-7d426cb7-9522-4dd7-a56b-55dd8cc1c8d0
- Both status checks for instance are marked as "passed": System reachability check passed and  Instance reachability check passed

This is how resource map looks on VPC: https://prnt.sc/BC3dSA5wSfca
This is how routes are configured in route table: https://prnt.sc/Qw-r186QyIHL
Security groups are configured like this:

- First security group created by bitnami: inbound rules (https://prnt.sc/7lPFyJeF344V); outbound rules (https://prnt.sc/kcZyib7xgVmo)
- Second security group created by bitnami: inbound rules (https://prnt.sc/HAFA6H793Mb8); outbound rules (https://prnt.sc/Df5DKbXLlo7t)
- THird security group created by bitnami: inbound rules (https://prnt.sc/10lhoYbZa1hv); outbound rules (https://prnt.sc/tPUkkt8PpRgW)
- Default security group: inbound rules (https://prnt.sc/6EwQZm6yhi6I); outbound rules (https://prnt.sc/Jx1Lg__3EQ15)

Network ACL is configured like this: inbound (https://prnt.sc/w_JufGp-1a_i), outbound (https://prnt.sc/XvBnbes0t2uS)

Regarding Bitnami - if I run this command "sudo /opt/bitnami/bndiagnostic-tool" I get the following output (excerpt):

```
? Resources: Found possible issues
? Connectivity: Found possible issues
✓ Mariadb: No issues found
✓ Processes: No issues found
? Wordpress: Found possible issues
? Apache: Found possible issues
✓ Php: No issues found
...
**Apache**
[Apache]
Press [Enter] to continue:
Found recent error or warning messages in the Apache error log.
[Sun Feb 26 20:59:56.709925 2023] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 952:tid
140329768302336] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client
**ip_address**:32977] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling),
referer:
https://www.<my-domain-name.com>/wp-admin/admin.php?page=w3tc_dashboard&_wpnonce=521586fa3b&
w3tc_note=flush_all
 [Sun Feb 26 20:59:43.844511 2023] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 952:tid
140330158352128] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client
**ip_address**:28814] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling),
referer:
https://www.<my-domain-name.com>/wp-admin/admin.php?page=w3tc_dashboard&_wpnonce=521586fa3b
 [Sun Feb 26 21:00:29.519343 2023] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 689:tid
140329474819840] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client
**ip_address**:51737] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling)
...
**[Wordpress]**
Found recent WordPress plugin related error messages in the Apache error log.

[Sun Feb 26 21:00:44.149415 2023] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 952:tid
140330003298048] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client
**ip_address**:20346] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling),
referer: https://www.<my-domain-name.com>/wp-admin/plugins.php?s=&plugin_status=all
```

Some of the videos I found on youtube suggest that running this command "sudo systemctl restart httpd" resolves the issue. I am not sure if this also applies to Bitnami. In any case, I cannot run this command with "bitnami" user and I keep getting this error "Unit httpd.service could not be found."

I can only connect to the instance using Putty and "bitnami" user. Connecting either with Putty or  EC2 Instance Connect as "ec2-user" or "admin" throws this error:

```
Failed to connect to your instance
Error establishing SSH connection to your instance. Try again later.
```

I am not a cloud expert. I can't figure out if the issue is with AWS or Bitnami or both.
But I wonder why is it so hard to bring the site back up since I "only" stopped and started an instance. My site is down for few days, so I'd appreciate any help.
Since I am not a cloud expert I would extremely appreciate very precise, step-by-step instructions on what needs to be done to bring the site back up.
If you need any additional information, please let me know and I will send the screenshots.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check bitnami docs for start/stop services:

> Each Bitnami stack includes a control script that lets you easily stop, start and restart services.
>
> Obtain the status of a service:
>
> sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh status
>
> Call it without any service name
> arguments to start all services:
>
> sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start
>
> Or use it to restart a single
> service, such as Apache only, by passing the service name as argument:
>
> sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
>
> Use this script to stop
> all services:
>
> sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh stop
>
> Restart the services by running
> the script without any arguments:
>
> sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/faq/administration/control-services/

Comment: Thank you good man! You are a genius! It worked when I ran this command "ctlscript.sh restart" This is life saving! Thank you!